# Facing problems with json decoding

Tags: python, json

I declared a variable which stores JSON file (output returned from subprocess).

```
app_data = self.run_subprocess(create_app)
```

Printed `app_data` looks like that:
(check comments for printed data)
I want to grab particular value from this str "appId", so I try to load app_data to json string and grab that value..

```
json_str = json.loads(app_data)
print(json_str["appId"])
```

Error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 190 column 1 (char 5767)
```

Comment: https://newtextdocument.com/776fb7d21b output was too big to post it so check it here

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the newtextdocument.com file: it loads without error.

Comment: I did json.loads on your post and it worked for me. json_str['appId'] returned '7f1f91c2-3b28-48ee-96ed-89080980'.

Comment: @BobbyOcean so strange.. can you share you code?

Comment: I simply copied your text in triple quotes x = """  """ and then ran import json, y = json.loads(x), and then y['appId'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine upon running it and return the value `7f1f91c2-3b28-48ee-96ed-89080980`. You can also confirm that it's a valid Json String by checking with a [validator here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

The error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 190 column 1 (char 5767)
```

I believe the error is to do with some malformed character on line 190, right after the line of the closing `}`. Find that and delete it and it should work fine

Comment: I guess you were right guyz.. wrote json to a file and saw this peace of garbage ``` [0m ``` :D